# How to handle a failed test in JBehave / Thucydides / Selenium?

Tags: selenium, jbehave, thucydides

I'm pretty new to Thucydides / JBehave, but haven't found any solutions posted to this one. This is the first time I've used Thucydides / JBehave, but have used Selenium before.

I have my .story file. The .story file lists 5 scenario's.
Each scenario is implemented in it's own POJO java class. 
e.g

```
public class ManagerBypassLoginSteps
{

@Steps
ManagerSteps managerSteps;

@Given("the manager is not logged in")
public void mangerLogsIn()
{
    managerSteps.start();
}

@When("the manager goes to a different page")
public void managerToDashboardPage()
{
    managerSteps.goesToDashboardPage();
}

@Then("they should see the login page")
public void managerShouldSeeLoginPage()
{
    managerSteps.verifyOnLoginPage();
    managerSteps.close();

}

}
```

The ManagerSteps class extends net.thucydides.core.steps.ScenarioSteps, but is otherwise just a POJO. The ManagerSteps calls the page objects - all very normal stuff and as per the examples.

In the scenario above, the test fails as the code displays an error message instead of returning the user to the log in page - that's fine, the security code doesn't meet the specified requirements (yet)  But, after the assert inside the ManagerSteps class fails, the test appears to stop. This means I have a browser instance just sitting there until I close it. When run as a series of tests, this means a broswer in the Selenium grid is now tied up.

I need a way to detect a test failure, to call to the page object to close / quit.

I can't find the equivalent of a @Before or @After that will always run,  I could find it I could use the @After to close the page object's webDriver.

I am not using Thucydides to manage the WebDriver lifecycle as I couldn't find any examples of this that did not use the ThucydidesRunner.class. 
Do I have to use the ThucydidesRunner.class ? My impression from the Thucydides manual for integrating with JBehave (http://thucydides.info/docs/thucydides/_writing_acceptance_tests_with_jbehave.html) didn't suggest it was required.

How does everyone else handle test failures in this situation ?

Comment: Using the simplest I can think of  try  
    {  
    assertThat(dashboardPage.getCurrentUrl()).isEqualTo(loginPage.getWebsiteUrl());  
    } catch (final Throwable e)  
    {  
    dashboardPage.close();  
    throw e;  
    }  but it just feels clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem I had was closing the browser, after a test failure.
The best way to manage the WebDriver appear to be to use the Thucydides @ManagedDriver annotation to handle the lifecyle.
I ended up using a very simple JUnit runner like so

```
public class UserLogin extends ThucydidesJUnitStory
{
@Managed
public WebDriver webdriver;

@ManagedPages(defaultUrl = "http://localhost:8080/dc-bus-main-web")
public Pages pages;
}
```

When this is started, it maps to the user_login.story file, through JBehave's naming convention, then starts normally.